# Copiar arquivos no c

Tags: c, cmd

Em linguagem C, como faço para copiar o arquivo `gg.bat` para  `"%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`

Tentei com

```
system("copy \"gg.bat\" \"%%appdata%%\\microsoft\\windows\\start menu\\programs\\startup\\\"");
```

Mas está aparecendo:

> A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretório ou do rótulo do
>   volume está incorreta.
>           0 arquivo(s) copiado(s).

Comment: Não se esqueça que o caracter "\"  é usado como prefixo de escape para várias letras dentro de uma string (por exemplo "\n" vira o caractere NewLine de código  10) - então use sempre duas barras  "\\" no nome do arquivo.

Comment: Outra: voce sabe que com sytem("copy") você não está "copiando o arquivo' em C, não é?  O copy é executado  um processo externo que faz a cópia. Uma cópia em C envolveria abrir o arquivo origiem para leitura, o arquivo destino paara escrita, e ler o conteudo de um e gravar no outro. Mas o efeito prático final do system("copy")  é o mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // aloca um texto para o system()
    char *command = malloc(
            strlen(argv[1])+ // tamanho da primeira string
            strlen(argv[2])+ // tamanho da segunda string
            32); // espaço extra

    sprintf(command, "cp \"%s\" \"%s\"", argv[1], argv[2]);

    system(command);

    return 1;
}
```

para chamar basta rodar o executável com 2 parametros: `<exe> <arquivo1> <arquivo2>`